# webhook telegram bot устанавливается только через Tor

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Webhook телеграм устанавливается только через Тор. Сам бот в телеграм не работает, не присылает ответ. Может ли это быть из-за расположения в России хостинга? (Да и сайт телеграмм не открывается с яндекс браузера и мозиллы)

Comment: Проделки РКН. У меня также.

Comment: Поможет ли смена хостинга? Не пробовали?

Comment: Разместил сервер во Франции.
До этих серверов еще не добрался.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, сайт. Интересуют цены.

Comment: Ovh.com - минимальный тариф 4.49$

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в блокировках РКН. Попробуйте разместить бота в другой стране, например, в США,используя бесплатный [хостинг](https://heroku.com)